# Laravel update creates a new record

Tags: laravel

AM trying to update existing record with eloquent via

```
 return Users::where('id', $id)
        ->update(['names' => $request->input("name")]);
```

But the above creates a new record. What am i missing on this?
I would like this to be one line as above.

Answer (score 2):

You have missed many things, such as coding convention of Laravel. Indeed, we usually create model in singular firm but you created "Users". Instead of "Users" you can create "User" model. And the syntax is also incorrect. So you can follow the below code. It should work if you have created table, model and controller in a correct way.

```
return User::where('id', $id)->first()->update(['name' => $request->input("name")]);
```

Or

```
return User::findOrFail($id)->update(['name' => $request->input("name")]);
```

Comment: The model was generated by artisan, ill try this thanks.

Comment: Seems the issue wasnt on laravel but vuejs when making my post and put request. Seems vuejs was making a post than a put request.